# About an error in Sublime 3

Tags: package, sublimetext3

Ok I start using sublime on archlinux, and I have an error that says:

```
Packages/User/Plain text-sublime. setting 1:1
```

What should I do to fix this?

Comment: What is the **exact** text of the error? Please take a screenshot and post it. What were you doing when it occurred? If you clear the error, does anything not work? Do you still get it after restarting Sublime? Please post the full contents of the file - it should be in `~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/User`. Use the [edit] link to add this information to your question, then post a comment when you've updated it.

Comment: Ok I will and no I try clear it... and it didnt work, I restart it... still didnt work...

Answer (score 0):

In Sublime, select **`Preferences -> Browse Packages...`** to open `~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages` in the file system browser (it's Nautilus on Ubuntu, don't know about Arch...). Open the `Users` folder, then delete `Plain text.sublime-settings`. You should no longer get the error message after restarting Sublime.